# Is there a way to disable a part of a inherited function through child class in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'm building a GUI Project in Java. In the parent class, I implemented MouseListener to highlight the button when the cursor hovers over it and stops when the cursor doesn't. I want to disable it in child class so that the button selected is then permanently highlighted showing that it was selected. In child class, when I hover over it, it again changes the color. I want to remove that specific part of the function from child class but I have to write it all over again to override the function. Is there any way I can disable that part in the child class?

Here's the code snippet

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    super.mouseEntered(e);
    if (e.getSource() == notifications) {
        notifications.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
    }
    if (e.getSource() == attendance) {
        attendance.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
    }
    if (e.getSource() == marks) {
        marks.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
    }
    if (e.getSource() == learning) {
        learning.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
    }
    if (e.getSource() == assignments) {
        assignments.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
    }
    if (e.getSource() == GDB) {
        GDB.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
    }
    if (e.getSource() == MDB) {
        MDB.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
    }
    if (e.getSource() == quizzes) {
        quizzes.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
    }
    if (e.getSource() == lectureContents) {
        lectureContents.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
    }
    if (e.getSource() == courseInformation) {
        courseInformation.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
    }
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    super.mouseExited(e);
    if (e.getSource() == notifications) {
        notifications.setBackground(null);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == attendance) {
        attendance.setBackground(null);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == marks) {
        marks.setBackground(null);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == learning) {
        learning.setBackground(null);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == assignments) {
        assignments.setBackground(null);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == GDB) {
        GDB.setBackground(null);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == MDB) {
        MDB.setBackground(null);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == quizzes) {
        quizzes.setBackground(null);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == lectureContents) {
        lectureContents.setBackground(null);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == courseInformation) {
        courseInformation.setBackground(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, in Java, not without an overriding method that overrides the parent class method entirely (particular copy/paste). It does not sound a good option and may be used when attempting to use a library that is hard to extend. If the code above is yours and you can redesign it, what you can do are at least: 1) provide a flag to the super class to control the behavior right in the super class; 2) redesign the super class to apply the Template Method design pattern to control the behavior from subclasses (may be an overkill for your case).

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: This can be helpful
https://www.baeldung.com/java-interface-segregation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods of your parent class are `public` I see no reason why you cannot simply override them and decide what you want to do:

**Parent.java:**

```
public class Parent implements MouseListener {
    @Override  
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // all your logic here to highlight when mouse entered/hovered
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // all your logic here for clearing the highlight when the mouse has exited or is not hovering over the component
    }
}
```

**Child.java:**

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    @Override  
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // we call super here as we want to inherit logic of the parent class for highlighting on mouse entered/hover
        super.mouseEntered(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // we dont call super here as we don't want to inherit the parents behavior
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. In the child class, reintroduce the property you don't want to change in the method body and write it on top in the MouseExited method and leave the body empty. Call the super.mouseEntered(e) function after that in the else part. This way the condition will be satisfied on the top and due to the empty body, nothing will be changed.
Here's the code

**Parent Class:**

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == dashboard) {
        dashboard.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
        dashboard.setForeground(Color.white);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == regCard) {
        regCard.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
        regCard.setForeground(Color.white);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == fees) {
        fees.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
        fees.setForeground(Color.white);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == resultCard) {
        resultCard.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
        resultCard.setForeground(Color.white);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == profile) {
        profile.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
        profile.setForeground(Color.white);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == logOut) {
        logOut.setBackground(new Color(0x13A89E));
        logOut.setForeground(Color.white);
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == dashboard) {
        dashboard.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        dashboard.setForeground(Color.black);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == regCard) {
        regCard.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        regCard.setForeground(Color.black);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == fees) {
        fees.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        fees.setForeground(Color.black);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == resultCard) {
        resultCard.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        resultCard.setForeground(Color.black);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == profile) {
        profile.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        profile.setForeground(Color.black);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == logOut) {
        logOut.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        logOut.setForeground(Color.black);
    }
}
```

**Child Class:**

```
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == dashboard) {
        //Do nothing
    } else {
        super.mouseExited(e);
    }
}
```